# Is my rabbit spayed or not

Tags: rabbits

Hi I was wondering if someone could help me I have a rabbit I brought from pets at home and she is lovely and now I am getting a male rabbit from a breeder I was wondering how do I tell if my female has been spayed because she isn’t aggressive never bit me and doesn’t spray

Answer (score 0):

Because spaying is an internal procedure, you likely won't be able to easily tell by yourself. However, a vet can tell you at your rabbit's next checkup. Before bringing a new bunny into your home, you should have your rabbit looked at by a vet anyway. They can check for common parasites and illnesses to make sure that your new rabbit won't be in danger of catching anything.